# Handling wrong address in mapview

Tags: iphone, ios, annotations, mkmapview

I am doing a map based application in iphone. I get my data(address) from the addressbook. The locations are pinned correctly when the right address is provided. But when a  wrong address(like XYZ instead of a correct city name like New York) is entered the pins fall to the (0,0) co ordinate of the map or to some random location in Canada. How can I handle this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could check for an invalid coordinate using the `kCLLocationCoordinate2DInvalid` constant, something like:

```
if ((coord.latitude == kCLLocationCoordinate2DInvalid.latitude) || (coord.longitude == kCLLocationCoordinate2DInvalid.longitude))
{
    NSLog(@"Invalid coordinate");
}
else
{
    // Valid coordinate, add it to the map
}
```